# SQL Server return StmtText when EXEC a SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with this when I try to Execute a simple Select Query. That I SELECT and it return the statement Text. But I expected it return a table. How can I did it?

**query**:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.R81BARCODE
```

**result**:

```
StmtText
-----------------------------
SELECT * FROM dbo.R81BARCODE

(1 row(s) affected)

StmtText
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([R50THIENAN].[dbo].[R81BARCODE].[PK_R81BARCODE]))

(1 row(s) affected)
```

[image: ERROR]

Comment: Do you have SHOWPLAN_TEXT on?

Comment: In the toolbar, there are icons for Show execution plan and others. Hover through them and toggle the one that displays data in a table.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mistakenly pressed `CTRL + D` which is a shortcut to output the result in **text format**

To get the results back to **Grid format** press `CTRL+T`.

From [**MSDN**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174205.aspx)

> CTRL+D  :  Output results in a grid
>   CTRL+T  :  Output results in text
>   format

Even in `SSMS TOOLBAR` you have a option to change this.

Comment: Thank you. But I mean that I expect It return a table with data. Not like this. You can see the results is display repeat my SQL Query: "SELECT * FROM dbo.R81BARCODE". It's not a result.

Answer (score 0):

What is being returned there is a Query Execution Plan, in text format. This normally means you have set SHOWPLAN_TEXT to ON. From the image you linked to, it looks like you have also set query results to "text" instead of grid.

To fix the output to return a result set instead of an execution plan, run the following statement:

```
SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT OFF
```

To return the results in a **grid** instead of text, click the "Results to Grid" button on the toolbar, or press **Ctrl-D**.

Comment: It's not effect with my problem. Here is the result in Grid mode. http://imageshack.com/a/img633/7978/ZSCaRO.png

Comment: what settings are enabled in "Tools > Options > Query Execution > SQL Server > Advanced"? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Here is advance option in tools. You can see in the picture below: http://imageshack.com/a/img633/3883/R4ow5H.png

Comment: I've tried to "Reset to default". But this problem still happen in my PC this time. So terrible :(

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> Advanced -> Uncheck/Untick SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT

And open new query window to validate.